# PHP - Need explanaiton end() with array

Tags: php, arrays

What is this and what does it do? Can you comment it?

`echo end($array)->id;`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php

Comment: Which part of the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) do you not understand? *"`end()` advances array's internal pointer to the last element, and returns its value."*

Comment: array may contain some objects , so its taking the last object in that array and calling the id property of that ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`end($array)` will be return the last element value of array. for example:

If `end(end($array))` is whatever then `whatever->id`

But I think in your case `end(end($array))` is `$whatever`

So `$whatever->id`  will be give some output.

Answer (score 2):

The end function gives the last element of a array.

In this case, the array is a **array of objects**, and from the last object in the array, the `id` property is returned.

Answer (score 2):

Have you read http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php? I think this is detailed in the content or comments.

Comment: you missed the part of pointing to a array of ojects, that is not so obvious. In this case, not a the last element from the array is returned, but a property from a object inside the array.

Comment: Pointing to a array of object is missing.

Answer (score 1):

`end()` advances array's internal pointer to the last element, and returns its value.

Answer (score 0):

End sets the internal pointer of an array to its last element. So

```
echo end($array)->id;
```

Echos out the id parameter of the last element in the array.